# The web application [...] appears to have started a thread named

Tags: multithreading, jvm, tomcat8

We have some web application running on tomcat8.
Here is system info:

`Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
JVM Version: 1.8.0_121-b13
JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 4.4.0-104-generic
OS Architecture: amd64`

All time (after rest controller function call, redeploy, restart etc...) there are errors all of them related to unstopped threads appear in the log:

`WARNING: The web application [newlps-1.0] appears to have started a thread named [CleanCursors-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.connection.ClusterDescription]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.`

The warning are appear for several thread names, not just one...
I have much to search over the internet about, and really doesn't found nothing really answers what to do...
I suppose that:
1. Thread need to "exit" after it finished.
2. There need be GC for clean old non referenced objects.

Why it doesn't works so?

Comment: are you using a connection pool? do you properly close it before you stop the application ?

Comment: I solved it with Context Listener? thanx )